# What is the current accepted taxonomy of the Citrus genus, and how do common cultivated fruits fit into it?

Tags: botany, taxonomy, agriculture

I want to learn about the taxonomy of *Citrus*, and how cultivated fruits fit into it. I know that the history of cultivated citrus fruits is full of hybridisation and that the taxonomic classifications have changed extensively over time, but I'm looking for the most up-to-date and *currently* accepted classifications.

Kew (Plants of the World Online) has information about which species names are currently accepted and which are synonyms. But there is no information about ancestry or about how cultivated plants fit into those species. Horticulture/agriculture widely use common names, and botany widely uses scientific names, but I'm looking for information that bridges these two areas.

I want to be able to write a full binomial *and* cultivar (if applicable) name for common citrus fruits. For example:

- "Meyer lemon". Is it *Citrus* × *meyeri*? *Citrus* × *limon* 'Meyer'? *Citrus* × *limon* var. *meyeri*?
- "Satsuma". Is it *Citrus unshiu*? *Citrus deliciosa*? *Citrus* × *deliciosa*? *Citrus aurantium* var. *unshiu*? *Citrus reticulata*?
- "Seville orange". Is it *Citrus* × *aurantium*? *Citrus aurantium* var. *aurantium*? *Citrus aurantium* 'Seville'?

Researching individual species or cultivars turns up some answers, but they often don't match *each other* because there are so many different sources. I want a cohesive summary of the current classification for the entire genus. Is there a book or article that can help me?

Comment: I don't have any sources for you, but I can tell you you're very likely going to find disagreement about classification,  taxonomy, and naming. Certainly some judgement calls will need to be made on your part, so make sure you're citing your sources and jotting down brief explanations why you choose one over the other. Ideally, you'd find 1 (maybe 2) sources to pull from to mitigate this problem, but if that's the case, then you'd probably not be tackling this project to begin with. Anyways, I'll keep my eyes open for helpful sources. Good luck!